# How to change what the axis of a plot is based on? (Python, Matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, regression

[image: The Data]

I want to create a graph of 2 * height (which is the meter values in the index) versus the time squared (which are the decimal values in the columns). How can I go about doing this? (In matplotlib)

For clarity, I want the y-axis to be 2 * index values, and the x-axis to be the times squared from within the columns. I would like this to be a series of line graphs

It should end up looking something like this:
[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how is it looks like?

Comment: I have tried just doing df1.plot(), which is not what I want (wrong axis labels -- y axis is time, and the x is the height). I do not know much about matplotlib, so this is why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you say you use `df1.plot()` to draw lines. `df.plot()` uses dataframe index as x values by default. You say *you want the y-axis to be 2 * index values, and the x-axis to be the times squared from within the columns*. Your demand involves changes to dataframe values, so I suggest you use `ax.plot()` for better customization.

Here is a program uses [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) which adopts [Least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) internally to get a matched line among given points.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""Height     Trial:1  Trial:2  Trial:3  Trial:4  Trial:5  Trial:6  Trial:7
1.029    0.4667    0.4616    0.4569    0.4579    0.4653    0.4578    0.4484
1.095    0.4752    0.4773    0.4721    0.4738    0.4713    0.4745    0.4663
1.168    0.4836    0.4834    0.4873    0.4890    0.4890    0.4904    0.4902
1.315    0.5139    0.5117    0.5161    0.5108    0.5224    0.5129    0.5187
1.540    0.5644    0.5677    0.5804    0.5535    0.5636    0.5605    0.5609
1.807    0.6051    0.6124    0.6014    0.6035    0.5977    0.6012    0.6209
""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, delim_whitespace=True)
df.set_index(['Height'], inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for column in df:
    x = df[column]**2
    y = df.index*2
    A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    k, b = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
    line = ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
    ax.plot(x, k*x+b, label=f'y={k:.5f}x+{b:.5f}', color=line[0].get_color(), linestyle='dashed')

plt.legend()

plt.xlabel('Fall time, squared (s²)')
plt.ylabel('Twice the height (m)')
plt.title('Measurement of Acceleration due to Gravity on Earth')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(list of things on x-axis, list of things on y-axs)
plt.show
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(times_squared_variable, 2_height_variable, '--', color='choose_a_color')

# Label axis and the plot
plt.xlabel('Name_x_axis')
plt.ylabel('Name_y_axis')
plt.title('Plot_name')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```